# How can I use GROUP_CONCAT in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, oracle, group-concat

I have the following query which I want to use with ActiveRecord so that it can be translated in native ORACLE based query on production server. Right now I am using SQLITe.

```
select c.name,co.code,GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS GroupedName
from countries c
INNER JOIN continents co
on c.continent_code = co.code
INNER JOIN event_locations el
on el.location_id = c.id
group by co.code
```

Comment: This is not a dup question at all. The OP wants to do the same using Rails. _voted_ to reopen it.

Comment: @Ben It is not duplicate. I clearly mentioned Rails in it

Comment: You want to have an Oracle query that does the same as the SQLite one? Or, you want someone to write you a load of RoR code that does the same thing? The first one is a duplicate; the second I agree wouldn't be.

Comment: I am talking about later. I know which methods provide similar functionality in SQLite and Oracle

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As long as I know, there's no `group_concat` equivalent in Rails, but you can use `includes` to do that:

```
continents = Continents
  .joins(:countries, :event_locations)
  .includes(:countries)
  .group("continents.code")

continents.each do |continent| 
  continent.countries.join(",")
end
```

This will produce only 2 queries - I know, is not so good as one, but I think that is the best than Rails can do without "group_concat". The other way will be something like that:

```
Country
  .select("countries.id, GROUP_CONCAT(countries.name) as grouped_name")
  .joins(:continents, :event_locations)
  .group("continents.code")
```

But if you do that, you need to change according to your database vendor.

- **MySQL**: group_concat(countries.name)
- **PostgreSQL**:
  string_agg(countries.name, ',')
- **Oracle**: listagg(countries.name, ',')

Comment: Yeah and figuring out driver at run and use apt query. I am surprised why was it not supported.

Answer (score 0):

On Rails 6 (I don't know in others), you can do generating only one query if you use `select`

```
continents = Continent.joins(:country).select(:name, 'countries.name as country_name')

countries_list = []

continents.each do |continent|
  countries_list << continent.country_name
end
```

I know the code is not grouping by the continent, but my idea was to show `how to make the query at once` and `how to access the result`. How to group you can do in the way it is better for you.

remember you need create the relationship in Continent class

```
has_many :country
```

hope I could help someone yet