# Rails ActiveQueryInterface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am facing a problem while I try to write a rails query using joins.

What I am building is a hash having candidate_answers grouped according to sections of a given question paper. (N.B. I have a pool of questions from where some are added in different sections of a questiion paper)

I have achieved my solution using map as:

```
exam_candidate.exam.question_paper.sections.includes(:questions).each do |section|
  if section.questions.present?
    section_question_hash[section] = candidate_answers.where(question_id: section.questions.map(&:id))
  end
end
```

Since using the above creates a lot of database queries running on the background, it is not healthy to use, and thus I need to use joins. Also, I am able to write a SQL query for the same as

```
select b.name, group_concat(c.id) from sections b
left join question_papers_questions a on a.section_id = b.id 
left join candidate_answers c on a.question_id = c.question_id 
where a.question_paper_id = 3 and c.exam_candidate_id = 4 
group by (b.name)
```

But while I try the same in rails I am having lots of issues with it.

Here's my model structure:

```
class ExamCandidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :candidate
  has_many :candidate_answers, dependent: :delete_all
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :candidate_answers
end

class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exam_candidates, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :candidates, through: :exam_candidates
  belongs_to :question_paper
end

class QuestionPaper < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exams, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :exam_candidates, through: :exams
  has_many :questions, through: :question_papers_questions
  has_many :question_papers_questions
  has_many :sections, dependent: :destroy
end

class QuestionPapersQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :question_paper
  belongs_to :section
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :candidate_answers, through: :answers
  has_many :exams, through: :question_papers
  has_many :exam_candidates, through: :exams
  has_many :question_papers_questions
  has_many :question_papers, through: :question_papers_questions
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question_paper
  has_many :questions, through: :question_papers_questions
  has_many :question_papers_questions
end

class CandidateAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam_candidate
  belongs_to :question
end
```

I have given enough time on it, but being almost a newbie in rails is my disadvantage, if anyone can try it or suggest something it would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you explain the issues you're having with the query? Do you need it converted to an activerecord query or can you just use the raw SQL?

Comment: I need it to get converted into active record query

Comment: Here is someone with a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146848/how-can-i-use-group-concat-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sections = exam.question_paper.sections.select("sections.name, group_concat(candidate_answers.id) as candidate_answer_ids")
  .joins(:question_papers_questions).joins("inner join candidate_answers on question_papers_questions.question_id = candidate_answers.question_id")
  .where(candidate_answers: {exam_candidate_id: id}, question_papers_questions: { question_paper_id: exam.question_paper_id })
  .group("sections.name")
```